# Save metadata of a form generated using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I generate a form with the following html dynamically using jquery:

```
<div id="form_container">
        <h1><a>Untitled Form</a></h1>
        <form action="save_form" method="post" id="newform" name="newform">
          <div class="form_description">
            <h2 class="editable">Form title. Click here to edit</h2>
            <p class="editable">This is your form description. Click here to edit.</p>
          </div>
          <ul id="form_body" class="ui-sortable">
          <li id="field1" class="world">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="hover">
            <label class="editable" for="field1">Text1</label>
            <input type="text" name="field1" value="">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="field2" class="world">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="hover">
            <label class="editable" for="field2">Paragraph2</label>
            <textarea cols="" rows="" class="textarea" name="field2"></textarea>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="field3" class="world">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="hover">
            <label class="editable" for="field3">Label3</label>
            <span id="field3">
            <input type="radio" id="field31" name="radiogroup" value="1" class="element radio">
            <label class="choice editable">option1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="field32" name="radiogroup" value="2" class="element radio">
            <label class="choice editable">option2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="field33" name="radiogroup" value="3" class="element radio">
            <label class="choice editable">option3</label>
            </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </form>
```

I would like to serialize metadata about the form to database and recreate it later.

```
- form title
- form description

Fields:
  - field name
  - field type
  - field_text
  - css class (if possible)
```

I have tried $('#newform').serialize() but it seems to be useful for just getting the name/value pairs of the fields like field1=&field2= and no information about the type of the field.

How do you get no form fields like the header, label etc?

Do I have to get the DOM node for #form_container and look for certain hardcoded values? 
Is there a better way to do it?

I am using jquery and rails (2.3.5)

thanks for your help.

**Update**

Based on Joey's answer, I came up with the following code that works for me:

```
$('#newform').find('input').each(function () {
    fields.push({
        name: $(this).attr('name'),
        type: $(this).attr('type'),
        text: $(this).val(),
        class: $(this).attr('class')
    });
    var label = $("label[for='" +  $(this).attr('name') + "']");
    if(label.length != 0) {
        fields.push({
            name: "label",
            type: 'label',
            text: label.text(),
            class: label.attr('class')
        });
    }
});

var form = {
    title: $('.form_description h2').text(), // or whatever the title is
    description: $('.form_description p').text(),
    fields: fields
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(form));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make the object yourself:

```
var fields = [];
$('#myFormTitle').find('inputs').each(function () {
  fields.push({name: $(this).attr('name'), type: $(this).attr('type'), text: $(this).val(), class: $(this).attr('class'), });
});

var form = {
  title: $('#myFormTitle').text(), // or whatever the title is
  description: 'This is a form',
  fields: fields
};
```

Then you could store it (this is just one option of many):

```
window.locationStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(form));
```

and

```
var form = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('form'));
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I am updating the post with the final code that worked for me.